# how to automatically get date in specific format from DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I'm using the component `DatePicker` from antd.

I have currently a `Form` from antd, in which there's a `Form.Item`, in which I put the `DatePicker`.

I want the `Form.Item` to be given the date in a specific format, lets say `YYYY-MM-DD`, is there a way to do that?

by giving it the prop `format` I can choose how it will look like in the UI but I'm trying to make it send back the value by the same format.

I've tried giving it a `dateFormat` prop with the function

```
function dateFormat(date) {
  return moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
}
```

but it doesn't work.

is there a way to do this manipulating the data in the onChange function?

Comment: Send it back where?

Comment: @MoaazBhnas I've added edit - I have currently a Form from antd, in which there's a Form.Item, in which I put the DatePicker.

Comment: Something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-17-0-alpha-5-forked-t4yox?file=/index.js?

Comment: I declared a state where I save a formatted date on each change which can be used anywhere.

Comment: @MoaazBhnas thanks but I'm asking if there's a way to parse the data in that format automatically through a prop/function of DatePicker or any other way - without adding external data manipulation?

Comment: I checked the props. I don't think there's a way to do so. `onChange` is all about reacting to the changes, not controlling how they're retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so apparently there's no way to do it in the props,
I've checked and so has @MoaazBhnas.

If anyone somehow finds a way, I'll be looking forward to hear!

Comment: This is comment not an answer

Comment: @SmitGajera No, it's an answer. I've asked if there's a way to do it automatically, and after a long search and other people's help - I found out there isn't a way. 
and that's the answer.